# in Oracle DB, is there a way to create an index on each column with one command?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c, ddl

Imagine I have at this point a table with 4 columns

```
describe TableA;
column1 varchar(10);
column2 varchar(10);
column3 varchar(10);
column4 varchar(10);
```

I want to create an index per each column , so I would

```
create index idx_1 on TableA(column1);
create index idx_2 on TableA(column2);
create index idx_3 on TableA(column3);
create index idx_4 on TableA(column4);
```

is there a way to achieve this easier ? is there a single line solution for this ?

Oracle database version in use is 12C

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Not you cannot**,
but you can write a query, which gives you that script

```
select  'create index IX_TA_' || COLUMN_NAME || ' on ' || TABLE_NAME || '(' || COLUMN_NAME || ');' as sql_ix
  from ALL_TAB_COLUMNS
 where table_name='TABLEA';
```

gives

```
SQL_IX
create index IX_TA_ID on TABLEA(ID);
create index IX_TA_COLUMN1 on TABLEA(COLUMN1);
create index IX_TA_COLUMN2 on TABLEA(COLUMN2);
create index IX_TA_COLUMN3 on TABLEA(COLUMN3);
create index IX_TA_COLUMN4 on TABLEA(COLUMN4);
```

and you can just copy paste and run...

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=dc1e908c2d7f772070a1db2a504a1f96

Answer (score 0):

NO!

you have to write script, give unique name to index, set columns/options and run it...

this one time thing, so it should not be so difficult...

Answer (score 0):

If you need 4 different indexes the only way could be by dynamic SQL:

```
begin
    for c in
        (
            select column_name
            from user_tab_columns
            where table_name = 'TABLEA'
        )
    loop
        execute immediate 'create index idx_' || regexp_substr(c.column_name, '\d+') || ' on tableA(' || c.column_name || ')';
    end loop;
end;
```

This is equivalent to

```
create index idx_1 on tableA(column1);
create index idx_2 on tableA(column2);
create index idx_3 on tableA(column3);
create index idx_4 on tableA(column4);
```

Of course this only makes sense if you have many columns, assuming that you need to create an index for ach column and that all the columns are named like columnXX.

Differently, if you need a single index over all the columns, you need

```
create index idx_XX on tableA(column1, column2, column3, column4)
```

but this depends on how you need to access the table